# Access to a detailTextLabel of a static cell in the function cellForRowAt

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I got a setting view, when I click on some cell, I got to a new view, in this second view I change some setting, when I come back in the setting view, I reload my tableView because I want change the detailTextLabel, I don't understand how can I call cellForRowAt() with a static table.

[image: TableViewStaticCell]

In red, the part I want to fill it from an array of data in each turn of cellForRowAt().
[image: My TableView]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use data source methods like `cellForRowAt` and `reloadData()` if the cells are static.

Use `IBOutlets` instead and assign the properties directly.

Answer (score 3):

**If you want to populate the cells from some data - such as an array. Then the cells are not static and will need to be changed to Prototype Cells.**

You then create a reuse identifier for the cell and dequeue that cell with the reuse identifier in the cellForRow method and set the detialTextLabel text from your data source for example: `cell.detailTextLabel.text = myArray[indexPath.row].settingName`.